# What is $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi k/n))$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\zeta_n$ be the $n$-th primitive root of unity and $4 \mid n$. Consider the field extensions $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi k/n) \subset  \mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$.

1. What is the degree of the extension $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_n):\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi k/n)]$?
2. What is  $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi k/n))$?

Comment: What is $k{}{}$?

Comment: I don't think that $\sin(2\pi k/n)$ is always an element of the cyclotomic field? For example, if $n=5$, $k=1$, then $\sin 72^\circ=\cos 18^\circ=\sqrt{2(5+\sqrt5)}/4$, which generates a quartic extension (see e.g. [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_constants)). But the real subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$?? OTOH, if $4\mid n$, then $i\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, and we have the obvious way of writing $\sin 2\pi k/n$ in terms of $\zeta_n^k$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Perhaps $\cos \frac{2 \pi k}{n}$ is meant, since Galois number fields are always closed under real parts.

Comment: @ZhenLin, that would be my guess as well. But in that case the answer to the question is very easy (and probably covered in most books on Galois theory). Let's just wait for the OP to clarify, whether the typo is about $\sin\leftrightarrow \cos$, or about forgetting the assumption $4\mid n$.

Comment: Duh. The best example showing that the problem is off is the case $n=3$: $\mathbb{Q}(\sin2\pi/3)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first prove that   $[\mathbb Q(\cos(2\pi /n)):\mathbb Q] =\phi(n)/2$, which is  easy.
Then you should use that $\sin(2\pi k/n)=\cos ((n-4k)\pi/2n)$.
A few calculations necessitating case distinctions will then yield the result:
$$[\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi /n)):\mathbb Q]=\phi(n)  \quad   \text {if} \;  n  \not \equiv  0 \;( \text {mod} \; 4) $$      $$[\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi /n)):\mathbb Q]=\phi(n)/2  \quad   \text {if} \;  n  \equiv 0 \;( \text {mod} \; 8)$$  $$[\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi /n)):\mathbb Q]=\phi(n)/4  \quad   \text {if} \;  n \equiv 4 \;( \text {mod} \; 8)$$ [I have answered your question in the above  form because (as Jyrki  noted) the original question doesn't make sense, since we don't always have  an inclusion $\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi /n))\subset \mathbb Q(\zeta_n).]$

Comment: How can we show $[\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi /n)):\mathbb Q]=\phi(n)/2  \quad   \text {if} \;  n  \equiv 0 \;( \text {mod} \; 8)$ from $\sin(2\pi k/n)=\cos ((n-4k)\pi/2n)$

Comment: @Mohan, if $\gcd(k,n)=1$, then $K=\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi k/n))$ is the real subfield of $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Therefore $[L:K]=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ we have
$$ \sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}. $$
Thus $\sin(2 \pi k/n)$ is, unless $n$ is a multiple of $4$, an element of
${\mathbb Q}(\zeta_{4n})$. The degrees of your extensions are basically
measured by the greatest common divisors of $k$ and $n$. There will be 
clean formulas for prime values of $n$, or e.g. if $k = 1$.