# Field Extensions over the Rationals

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. For which values of $p$ is the following true:
>   $$\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right),\cos\left(2\pi/p\right)\right)=\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right)\right),$$
>   where those are field extensions over $\mathbb{Q}$.

From
$$p-1=[\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi/p}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi/p}):\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right),\cos\left(2\pi/p\right)\right)]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right),\cos\left(2\pi/p\right):\mathbb{Q}\right)]$$

I get
$$[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right),\cos\left(2\pi/p\right)\right):\mathbb{Q}]=\frac{p-1}{2}.$$

But then $$[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right),\cos\left(2\pi/p\right)\right):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right),\cos\left(2\pi/p\right):\mathbb{Q}\sin(2\pi/p)\right)]\cdot[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right)\right):\mathbb{Q}]$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{p-1}{2}=[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right),\cos\left(2\pi/p\right):\mathbb{Q}\sin(2\pi/p)\right)].[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right)\right):\mathbb{Q}]$$

I came across the following article [What is $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi k/n))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136723/what-is-operatornamegal-mathbb-q-zeta-n-mathbb-q-sin2-pi-k-n/136757#136757) which states that (since clearly $p$ prime $\Rightarrow p$ is not $0\mod4$) $$[\mathbb{Q}(\sin(2π/p)):\mathbb{Q}]=ϕ(p)=p-1$$

which forces $$[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sin\left(2\pi/p\right),\cos\left(2\pi/p\right):\mathbb Q(\sin(2\pi/p)\right)]=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Clearly something went wrong but I'm not sure what - I have a feeling I'm making some elementary error.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $c=\cos(2\pi/p)$, $s=\sin(2\pi/p)$ note that $\mathbb Q(c,s,i)=\mathbb Q(\zeta_{4p})$ (because $i(c+is)$ is a primitive $4p$<sup>th</sup> root of unity and on the other hand $i=\zeta_{4p}^p, c=\frac{\zeta_{4p}+\zeta_{4p}^{-1}}2,s=\frac{\zeta_{4p}-\zeta_{4p}^{-1}}{2i}$) and is of degree $\phi(4p)=2(p-1)$ over $\mathbb Q$ and clearly of degree 2 over $\mathbb Q(s,c)$. Hence I get $[\mathbb Q(s,c):\mathbb Q]=p-1$, not $\frac{p-1}2$.

---

Aiming at the original question:

From expanding $(c+is)^p=1$ and taking the real part, we find a polynomial for $c$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q(s)$ and such that only *odd* powers of $c$ appear (because only even powers of $is$ appear in the real part). Since $c^{2k+1}=c\cdot (1-s^2)^k$ we obtain in fact a linear polynomial for $c$, hence see directly that $\mathbb Q(s,c)=\mathbb Q(s)$.